# How to change section location of a UITableViewCell on tap

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to add a UITableViewCell to another UITableView section whenever a button on the cell is tapped. However, I'm quite confused about the process of how to change a cell's section location after it has already been loaded into the table view. Currently I have two sections and am adding 5 custom UITableViewCells into the first section.

Any ideas on how to move the cells to the second section on tap?

Here are cell and section methods in my view controller class:

```
var tableData = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five"]

// Content within each cell and reusablity on scroll
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var tableCell : Task =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Task
        tableCell.selectionStyle = .None
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

    var titleString = "Section \(indexPath.section) Row \(indexPath.row)"
        tableCell.title.text = titleString
    println(indexPath.row)

    return tableCell
}

// Number of sections in table
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

// Section titles
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0 {
        return "First Section"
    } else {
        return "Second Section"
    }
}

// Number of rows in each section
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return tableData.count
    } else if section == 1 {
        return 0
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a separate datasource for first and second sections. When button is tapped, modify datasource and move cell to new section with `moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath newIndexPath: NSIndexPath)` UITableView method.

For example:

```
var firstDataSource = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five"]
var secondDataSource = [ ]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return section == 0 ? firstDataSource.count : secondDataSource.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = indexPath.section == 0 ? firstDataSource[indexPath.row] : secondDataSource[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

// For example, changing section of cell when click on it.
// In your case, similar code should be in the button's tap event handler
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if indexPath.section == 0
    {
        let data = firstDataSource[indexPath.row]

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        secondDataSource.append(data)
        firstDataSource.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: find(secondDataSource, data)!, inSection: 1)

        tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, toIndexPath: newIndexPath)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that was perfect, exactly what I was looking for. If you don't mind me asking, where did you learn to develop iOS apps and how long have you been doing it for? I'm still a beginner, but I'm curious in regards to the processes others took to become well versed at this. Let me know if you can, thanks a ton!